# Morfik is it really a good choice for my next web application [please advise]

Tags: morfik

I am going to build an ecommerce and paypal listing web application and since morfik become a free tool I am thinking to use it for flexibility and reduce development time as I heard

but while I am surfing I find also some pitfalls like lack of support:
http://forum.morfik.com/posts/18187?liststyle=Tree

And packages that enable real world solutions are for subscribers only (hidden fees ?)

so what you think ? I appreciate opinions specially from people that already use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have been a delphi fan for years. I am not technical, I get there by dogged determination and have written some very complex apps running in important commercial setups.  I chose delphi because in the early days it managed most of the techy stuff for me and was quick. In the 15 years of use I have never been able to adapt to web apps.  Interweb was great but required ISAPI platform not always available from ISPs and deployment was just so fiddly.
I tried MORFIK and built and deployed a reasonable web app within a morning. Just like the old delphi, it has wizards and tools that do all the work.  All for no cost!!  £16 per month gets you a whole lot more as I understand it and I am very tempted.
Database is firebird, wish it were my sql but it works.  Not certain about scaled up performance so checking such things out.  These guys are on the right track but they need support and capital to continue as the early delphi developed.

Answer (score 1):

I will just add that morfik uses Firebird by default but can connect to several other db's via ODBC.